# Launch exe file from local intranet page mozilla

Tags: file, exe, mozilla

the following link will be opened. But then I get the following window, unfortunately.

[image: .Exe download confirmation screen]

In the handler.json I have made the following entries to force opening the exe file, but it does not work.

`"application/exe":{"action":2,"ask":true,"extensions":["exe"]},`

How can I get the Exe File open? Is there any cheat around the security setting of Firefox or Chrome to work around. By the way, IE works fine.

Comment: Hi, it looks like the beginning of your question might be missing?

Comment: Hi, sorry my link in the HTML File -->   <a href="#" onclick="window.open('file:///C:/Users/yc0rk9c/Desktop/agree Voice.lnk')">   TEST</a>

Comment: You should be able to edit your question and add that in :).  You can use the backtick characters around the code to get it formatted as code too.